# How to connect Azure SQL database with Visual Studio 2019 without connection errors [Error Number: 10060]

Tags: azure, visual-studio, azure-sql-database, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to connect to my Microsoft Azure SQL database to Visual Studio 2019. I've tried signing in using SQL Server Authentication, included the password and proceed to "Connect". However, I'm unable to connect and it returns with the error number 10060.

These are the settings (including) in Azure which I configured before opening Visual Studio 2019.

1. Under set firewall - Public Network, selected "selected networks"
2. Enabled allow Azure services and resources to access this server.

Additional information

1. Error number 10060 means the SQL Server client cannot connect to the server
2. The same error appears when I tried connecting to Azure Data Studio.
3. The server I am trying to connect to is a Development server.

Comment: Try to connect through SSMS and let me know if you can

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL SERVER error 10060 can be caused by that the default SQL Server settings do not allow remote connections as mentioned in [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/mssqlserver-10060-database-engine-error?view=sql-server-ver16)
As mentioned by @Lakshmi Vijayakumar's document there are multiple ways for 10060 error

- ##### MySQL configuration issues
- ##### Firewall restrictions
- ##### Wrong MySQL connection string

Refer his [Document](https://bobcares.com/blog/cannot-connect-to-mysql-server-10060/#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9C%20Cannot%20connect%20to%20mysql%20server%20%2810060%29%20%E2%80%9D,is%20MySQL%20service%20not%20running%20on%20the%20server.) it may help to resolve your issue.
Also, you can refer @Vamshi B latest  [article](https://sqlserver-dba.co.uk/sql-server/sql-server-error-10060-severity-0-an-error-has-occurred-while-establishing.html)